# How Reverse Iterator in C++ works

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

am beginner to c++ and i want to know how operator ++ moves iterator backward. As i know iterator.begin() and iterator.end() returns pointer to fist index and last index respectively.

```
vector<int>::iterator it = myvector.begin();
```

when we do **it++** it will move to next index. this is clear to me but i am completely confused with reverse iterator.

```
vector<int>::reverse_iterator rit = myvector.rbegin();
```

when we do **rit++** it will move to backward. I want know how this is implemented in case of reverse iterator. Is it operator overloading or something which i don't know. Please give me right way to understand these things.

please give more detail knowledge.

Comment: There is a good explanation here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator.

Comment: thanks for the given link. It cleared the concept. Can you please give me the link which will show the clear implementation of operator++ function of reverse_itrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As i know `iterator.begin()` and `iterator.end()` returns pointer to fist index and last index respectively.

Close, but not necessarily:

- they return `iterator`s, not pointers....
- `end()` returns an iterator that's notionally "past" the last valid index.

Internally the `vector` `iterator`s normally do store pointers though, and a `++` or `--` on the `iterator` goes through a forwarding overloaded operator to perform a corresponding `++` or `--` on the pointer.

For reverse iterators, the overloaded `operator++` simply performs a `--` on the pointer, and vice versa.  For example, the Visual C++ library on my computer does this in `class _Revranit`, from which `reverse_iterator` is derived:

```
    _Myt&  operator++()
            {
            --current;
            return (*this);
            }

    _Myt  operator++(int)
            {
            _Myt _Tmp = *this;
            --current;
            return (_Tmp);
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do `it++` or `rit++` they don't really mean "move forward or backward in the collection", they both mean "move to the next element you want to iterate over".

If you use `begin()`, you're saying "I want to iterate forwards", so `it++` moves forwards.

If you use `rbegin()`, you're saying "I want to iterate backwards", so `rit++` moves backwards.

Answer (score 2):

```
_***************_
 ^begin ++--->  ^end
^rend <---++   ^rbegin
```

Comment: probably some explanation would make this response far better!

Comment: If I add some explanation i will duplicate other answers. I just think that in this case a picture is better then hundredth of words.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is operator overloading. When you do `rit++`, the compiler internally translates that do

```
rit.operator++(0);
```

Here, `operator++` is a method of the reverse iterator class that knows how to move the iterator. The dummy integer argument is needed to [differentiate between prefix and postfix `operator++`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15244185/367273).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a [reverse_iterator::operator++](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/reverse_iterator/operator++/) overload which advances "backwards" from the last element to one-before-the-beginning.

The behavior is equivalent to (the page on cppreference might contain another possible implementation)

```
    reverse_iterator operator++(int)
    {
      reverse_iterator __tmp(*this); 
      --current; // This is an internal iterator
      return __tmp;
    }
```

Notice that how this is exactly accomplished might vary from implementation to implementation. As far as you comply with the standard requirements, you have some degrees of freedom.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between a reverse iterator r and the iterator i it is constructed from is:

```
&*r == &*(i-1)
```

If *end* is the one-past-the-end element in a sequence, then the first element in the reversed sequence points to *(*end* – 1 )