# Overloaded ++ operator only works from left side (C++)

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading, rvalue

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Color { RED, GREEN };

Color& operator++(Color& source)
{
    switch (source)
    {
        case Color::RED:    return source = Color::GREEN;
        case Color::GREEN:  return source = Color::RED;
    }
}

int main()
{

   Color c1{ 1 };
   Color c2 = Color::RED;

   ++c1;  // OK
   std::cout << (int)c1 << std::endl;

   c2++;  // error
   std::cout << (int)c2 << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

I overloaded ++ operator but it only works from left hand side.
What is the reason behind it?

Is it related to the way I do overloading or is it related to lvalue-rvalue concept?

Comment: I think there are different overloads for post increment and pre increment operators. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/15244094/4688321.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Color& operator++(Color& source)` is for pre-incremant,

you need

`Color operator++(Color& source, int)` for post increment.

Comment: @arda30 • Note that the `int` second parameter is a dummy parameter and is only used to indicate that the operator++ is postfix.

Comment: @molbdnilo: fixed.