# I was doing code on operator overloading . while i encoutered a strange behaviour can any one explain it?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pre-increment

** Pre Increment **

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class demo {
    int i;
    public:
    demo (int b = 0) {
        i = b;
    }
    void display() {
        cout<<"Number is " <<i<<endl;

    }
    void operator ++() {
        i = ++i;
    }
};

int main() {
    demo obj(5);
    obj.display();
    ++obj;
    obj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

*In this case operator function took no function argument*

** Post Increment **

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class demo{
    int i;
    public:
        demo (int b = 0 ){
            i = b;
        }
        void display(){
            cout<<"Number is " <<i<<endl;

        }
        void operator++(int){
            i = i++;
        }
};

int main(){
    demo obj(5);
    obj.display();
    obj++;
    obj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

*While in this code the function took the int as and argument*

In these codes almost everything is same except for the fact that in one code *void operator ++()* takes a argument int while in other it doesn't .

What could be the possible reason of such behaviour ?

Comment: thats not the only difference. One callls `i = ++i;` the other `i = i++;`, both should actually be  just `++i`

Comment: Thats the syntax for overload the pre cs post increment operator, otherwise the functiom declarations would be the same.

Comment: "What could be the possible reason of such behaviour ?" what behavior? You didnt say what is "strange"

Comment: Depending on C++ standard used by the compiler, `i = i++` might be *undefined behavior*. Later versions of the standard made it sequenced IIRC.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What do you mean by "strange behaviour"? It **seems as though** you are asking "why does `operator++` have a parameter when it is used to implement post-increment, but not when it is used to implement pre-increment?". The answer is: because *that is how the compiler knows which thing you are implementing*.

Comment: If it's about the argument to Your `operator++` function, please take some time to think about how the compiler would know which function to call if both post- and pre-increment both used the same function signature. And remember that you can overload *both* operators in the same class.

Comment: The pre/post increment operators are supposed to return a value, a different one. As is you only have an "increment" operator that is neither pre nor post and also UB in older C++ versions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking why one takes a parameter and one does not. I could only say, that is just the syntactical convention in C++ to distinguish prefix increment and postfix increment.

In your above code, the resultant object is always incremented after you use the operator `++`. Therefore, you would not likely to see a desirable result. You can only notice their difference it you assign `demo x = a++;` or `demo x = ++a;` (getting their current value), and then print the value out.

To do that, you have to do something like below:

*Prefix increment increases, and return itself.*

```
demo& operator ++() {
    i = i + 1;
    return *this; // Return itself after incremented
}
```

*Meanwhile, postfix increment creates a duplicate object, increases itself, and return the duplicate one.*

```
demo operator++() {
    demo duplicate(i);
    i = i + 1;
    return duplicate; // Return the itself but before incremented.
}
```

You can read this familiar post: [Overloading ++ for both pre and post increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15244094/overloading-for-both-pre-and-post-increment)